# Arrayformula with if condition - only hiding row values instead of not including them

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here is my test sheet for solving this problem:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UnYxy2HXPqA5aBr2WLHVFccktOBEgde-Chly2jna11k/edit?usp=sharing

1st sheet is a manually entered dump/log of calls
2nd sheet is supposed to be a daily report where user can type the date needed to print

The formula I used is `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF('Call Log Details'!A2:A=D1,{'Call Log Details'!A2:A,'Call Log Details'!B2:B,'Call Log Details'!D2:D,'Call Log Details'!N2:N,ARRAYFORMULA(IF('Call Log Details'!E2:E="",,"IN................: " & 'Call Log Details'!A2:A & " " & 'Call Log Details'!B2:B & CHAR(10) & "CALLER.....: " & 'Call Log Details'!E2:E & CHAR(10) & "TEL#..........: " & 'Call Log Details'!G2:G & CHAR(10) & "PATIENT.....: " & 'Call Log Details'!D2:D & CHAR(10) & "CALL TYPE: " & 'Call Log Details'!I2:I & CHAR(10)& CHAR(10) & "MESSAGE.: " & CHAR(10) & 'Call Log Details'!J2:J & CHAR(10) & CHAR(10) & "NOTES......: " & 'Call Log Details'!T2:T)),'Call Log Details'!P2:P},))`

It is comparing the date values for the two sheets. I think the comparison is correctly identifying the values needed. The problem I think is how I setup the array, because for example if I put 2/11/21 it will show the rows for 2/11/21 but instead of putting it in the first row, it goes in the 2nd row. But if I put 3/1/21, it shows both rows of 3/1/21 but in rows 1 and 3 skipping row 2. It might be that it is just copying all rows and just hiding the values depending on dates.

What I am looking as a result is when if I put 2/11/21, then it will be in the first row and not including 3/1/21. While if I put 3/1/21, it will show both 3/1/21 values in the first 2 rows and not including 2/11/21.

Comment: The reason for the rows coming out the way they do is because of your initial IF statement.  If the date = your entry date, return the data.  When the date in the Call Log doesn't match, it basically returns a blank row.  There are other ways of restructuring your formula.  I'll have something here in a little bit.

Comment: Someone suggested to use the FILTER function instead. It looks like it is working as needed. How would I know when to use array or filter? Because Ive used array in other cases but they skipped as well. Im still new to sheets and I confuse when to use array, index, filter, and query a lot still.

Comment: If there's another way you can do it, i'd love to learn about it as well since I'm learning google sheets altogether and the more info I acquire the better for future problems. Thank you very much!

Comment: A suggestion:  your date fields are text strings, not real dates, whcih can sometimes be confusing.  Let me know if you want me to show you a revised format, on my copy of your tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [GK-Printer Friendly tab](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UnYxy2HXPqA5aBr2WLHVFccktOBEgde-Chly2jna11k/edit#gid=242148483&range=A19) in your sheet.

I've switched to a QUERY, and simplified things by adding a helper column in column Z of the Call Details tab (see my copy of it, [GK-Call Details](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UnYxy2HXPqA5aBr2WLHVFccktOBEgde-Chly2jna11k/edit#gid=1149254499&range=Z1:Z3)).

The formula is now:

```
=query('GK-Call Log Details'!A2:Z," 
   select A,B,D,N,Z,P where A = '"&D1&"' order by A,B,D",0)
```

In Call Details, column Z (my copy) I'm doing the merger of the notes fields, which greatly simplifies the final result.  This column could be hidden in Call Details, or it could be moved to a different tab, so it shouldn't be an inconvenience.

Comment: Is it always the case that adding another column in the main sheet with calculations better than just calculating those rows on the sheet you want to add it to? If not, how do I know which case will be better in the different situations?

Comment: Thanks for teaching me another way and it looks like it is working as intended.

Comment: Note that it would be possible to eliminate the "helper column", and combine everything into one formula, but it would be quite ugly, and more confusing to maintain or change, so I don't recommend that.  Helper columns can greatly simplify things, and show the logic more easily, especially if you are just starting off with this type of complex spreadsheet.